# String hostname from properties file: Java

Tags: java, string, config, host, jedis

This may sound like a really simple problem but I can't figure out a way around this.

I have a config.properties file which contains two key values: an IP address and a Port number. I read this config file to extract the key values in string format. However, when I am trying to use these values, I am unable to connect to the IP address retrieved from the config file.

The reason is that the values read are in string format and I need to convert them to proper formats before using them. What I want is that the value "192.168.1.40" stored in config file is converted to a `String host` format. I tried using InetAddress but that gives an error.
The contents of the config file are:

```
IP=192.168.1.40
PORT=9124
```

The code that uses these values is as follows:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
String propFileName = "...//testJedis//resources//config.properties";        
prop.load(new FileInputStream(propFileName));//testJedis/resources/config.properties"));// configStream);

Jedis jedis=new Jedis(prop.getProperty("IP"),Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("PORT")));
//Jedis jedis = new Jedis("192.168.1.40",9124);
```

The error stack I obtain is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: "192.168.1.40"
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:92)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:84)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:65)
at TestJedis.main(TestJedis.java:43)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: "192.168.1.40"
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144)
... 5 more
```

The documentation of jedis class can be found [here](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html)!

P.S.: If I directly pass the host address as string, it works properly (that means the host is perfectly reachable).

Comment: Could you store the two properties read (the string and the int) in separate variables and log them on screen just to be sure?

Comment: Any whitespace characters sneaking in somewhere?

Comment: The stack says you have an UnknownHostException; its attempting to connect to that IP. Are you able to connect without the prop. file?

Comment: Use `prop.getProperty("IP").trim()` and try.

Comment: @Grimmy: I can read the variable properly. IP is returned as "192.168.1.40" (quotes included) when I print them on screen.

Comment: @NilsH: I haven't used any whitespace character and tried trim() also as suggested by TAsk

Comment: In debug mode, check for values of prop.getProperty("IP") and prop.getProperty("PORT"). If using eclipse, create a breakpoint and use ctrl+shift+i to see the values of above line of code.

Comment: can you try creating a new file in notepad with your entries ? May be some char encoding causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: "192.168.1.40"
                               ^            ^
```

*IMHO* this double quotes shouldn't be there as this `Exception` takes `String` as an argument of hostName which is unknown.
The only reason of this `Exception` can be that you are actually passing double quotes in `hostName`.

It should be `java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.12<--If host is unknown`

*From Comment*

> IP is returned as "192.168.1.40" (quotes included) when I print them
>   on screen

Which simply means your `String IP="\"192.168.1.40\""` not `String IP="192.168.1.40"`
remove double quotes from configuration file.

I am unable to reproduce the issue but you can just use `replace`

```
String ip=prop.getProperty("IP").replace("\"","")
```

Comment: The contents of the config file are mentioned in the question. I haven't added any quotes and I am still facing problem reading it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. Even though I haven't added any quotes in the config file, I am not able to read the value as 'just a string'.

Comment: Is it happening for PORT also?

Comment: No, PORT is read absolutely fine. The problem is that when I am using "." in the value field, the format is changing. If I set the property using prop.setProperty("IP","192.168.1.40") the program works fine. I guess there is some proble using the "." in value. I tried using \ to escape the meaning but it does not help.