# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, jedis, amazon-elasticache

I'm using Jedis to connect to my Redis instance/cluster in AWS, but I kept getting this error, here's the code, I searched extensively on SO, found the closest one is: [String hostname from properties file: Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448887/string-hostname-from-properties-file-java)

I tried both ways, neither worked for me.
So please help.

Here's my Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AWSCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
            + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
            + "location (/Users/USERNAME/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
    }

    AmazonElastiCacheClient client = new AmazonElastiCacheClient(credentials);
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_2));
    DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();
    dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);

    DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = client.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);
List<CacheCluster> cacheClusters = clusterResult.getCacheClusters();
        for (CacheCluster cacheCluster : cacheClusters) {
        for (CacheNode cacheNode : cacheCluster.getCacheNodes()) {
            String addr = cacheNode.getEndpoint().getAddress();
            int port = cacheNode.getEndpoint().getPort();
            String url =  addr + ":" + port;
            System.out.println("formed url is: " + url);

            Jedis jedis = new Jedis(url);
            System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully");
            // check whether server is running or not
            System.out.println("Server is running: " + jedis.ping());
        }
    }
```

The last line in the above code keeps throwing this error, here's the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: REDISNAME.nquffl.0001.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:126)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:121)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:106)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:195)
at sporadic.AmazonElastiCacheClientExample.main(AmazonElastiCacheClientExample.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: REDISNAME.nquffl.0001.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
... 11 more
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please point out.

Comment: is your redis cluster is allowing inbound traffic on port 6379 ?

Comment: Is this code running on an AWS server in the same VPC as the ElastiCache cluster? I don't believe you can expose ElastiCache clusters outside your VPC. Also, as AmitK stated, is the port open in the Security Group assigned to the cluster?

Comment: @AmitK Yes, the Security Group I used to launch this Redis cluster has Protocol: All, Port Range: All.

Comment: @fishercoder1534 where you are running your app ? inside AWS or in your local system ? also please refer the below answer given by me.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was running it in my local machine, thanks for pointing it out, I'm deploying my code to an EC2 instance inside the same VPC and rerun it from there, then I'll update here.

Comment: @fishercoder1534 , cool let me know if it works.

Comment: Just to keep you posted, I'm blocked by another thing: I'm not able to scp my code into my EC2 instance, here's the issue: the normal process for me is to ssh into my EC2 instance and then do $su -l ANOTHER_USER, to gain ANY access, otherwise I'm not able to do anything on this EC2 instance and always returns me "Permission denied". So, now I tried to scp my code to my EC2 instance, it says "Permission denied". Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks. Basically, how to do $scp -i MY.pem MY_CODE me@my_ec2_instance with $su -l ANOTHER_USER together.

Comment: @fishercoder1534 you can simply SCP your code to /tmp folder of your ec2 instance and then move this code to any users home directly from there. also add @ user tag to notify the people for fast response.

Comment: Cool, thanks, it worked. But I just found that on my EC2 instance, there's nothing, even no Java, so I'm installing everything to compile/run this code, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @fishercoder1534 sure , lets continue discussing this in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132049/discussion-between-amitk-and-fishercoder1534).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to AWS Documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html

> Amazon ElastiCache is an AWS service that provides cloud-based
>   in-memory key-value store. On the back end it uses either the
>   Memcached or Redis engine. The service is designed to be accessed
>   exclusively from within AWS. However, **if the ElastiCache cluster is
>   hosted inside a VPC, you can use a Network Address Translation (NAT)
>   instance to provide outside access.**

So you have below two options :-

1. Either you host your app inside the AWS and have proper security group setting to allow access to your elastic-cache cluster from your ec2-instance where your app is deployed.
2. If you want to run your app outside of AWS then you have to modify the Network Address Translation (NAT) to provide outside access.

IMO, its easy to deploy the code in AWS-Ec2 instance and test it if you are not very familiar with the networking and NAT.

I used to have locally memcache and redis instance where i used to connect for local developement and for other environment like qa,stg,prod used to deploy it in AWS ec2 instance.

Let me know if you any issues.

Answer (score 6):

Your setting shoud be this way :

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("REDISNAME.nquffl.0001.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com",6379);
```

NOT this way :

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("REDISNAME.nquffl.0001.apn2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the 6379 port was not accepting connections, so I changed I configured Redis with different port, and it worked.